# Enable Deskband programmatically

Tags: winapi, deskband

We have developed a custom Deskband by implementing the IDeskBand interface.

As a part of the deployment strategy we would like to enable the Deskband automatically.

Can anyone provide guidance on how this could be achieved, either programmatically or other?

Comment: Deskbands are deprecated and not recommended for use any more. Are you sure this is the best approach?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx#band_registration

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090202-00/?p=19303 short answer: you shouldn't be doing this.